# Survey App Model in Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

js and for my first application I'm trying to write a survey application. My idea is to have a surveys route that list surveys available, and  when you click on the survey it loads the questions in that survey. Each survey would have its on template used to display the questions in a particular way. So I'm starting off with this.

http://jsbin.com/uVoTOyOdo/1/edit

My question is how can I link a particular set of questions and template to a survey? Ideally I'd like the user to have the ability to create the questions and pick a template.   I don't have the surveys route in the router map yet, because I'm not sure how to link the surveys and their questions to a  particular survey using the FixtureAdapter, so when a survey is clicked on the right questions come up for the survey. Also is it a good idea to have things nested like this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to override renderTemplate hook on the survey route.

```
App.SurveyRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('dynamic_template_name');
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: thanks, How will ember know which questions to grab for a particular survey?

Comment: You'd do that in the model hook, based on the dynamic portion of the url, and then you'd have some property on the model saying which template to use.

Comment: So in the model hook I'd parse the dynamic segment and use that id to load some json question objects with the same name? Can you give me an example if thats ok?

Comment: Or is it better to have a SurveysRoute listing the surveys and have one big JSON object with questions and a template type with them? I'm still in FIXTURES mode.

Comment: i can set up an example, but i just had shoulder surgery, so it'll take me a while, slow typing and awesome drugs